# JSON, jQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json

How to get the index of a particular object from a JSON file?

I have a JSON file with below content.

```
[
    {
        "time": "2017-04-11T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "Meep meep!  ",
        "handle": "@roadrunner"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-05-20T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "Th-th-th-th-That's all, folks!  ",
        "handle": "@porkypig"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-05-15T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 3,
        "comment": "Be very, very quiet! ",
        "handle": "@ElmerFudd"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-04-16T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "What's up, doc? ",
        "handle": "@bugsbunny"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-04-18T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 3,
        "comment": "You're deth-picable!",
        "handle ": "@daffyduck"
    }
]
```

and Below is my HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="label"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'document.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).each(function (index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                $("#label").append(value.score);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

With the above code i am getting the all the scores in my div with id="label".
Output="00303"

What if i want the score of third object from the object array in JSON? 
i.e only "3"

Comment: Assuming you just want the third object in the array, access it by index: `data[2].score`

Comment: data[2].score ?

Comment: so i do not have to use value anymore? where can i use data[2].score?

Answer (score 1):

two options.

1st, use `data[2].score`

2nd, inside your each, check the index, example:

```
            if(index === 2){
              $("#label").append(value.score);
            }
```

### Option 1: Using data[2].score:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "time": "2017-04-11T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "Meep meep!  ",
        "handle": "@roadrunner"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-05-20T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "Th-th-th-th-That's all, folks!  ",
        "handle": "@porkypig"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-05-15T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 3,
        "comment": "Be very, very quiet! ",
        "handle": "@ElmerFudd"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-04-16T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 0,
        "comment": "What's up, doc? ",
        "handle": "@bugsbunny"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-04-18T22:31:50.3369265Z",
        "score": 3,
        "comment": "You're deth-picable!",
        "handle ": "@daffyduck"
    }
]

console.log('3rd score: ' + data[2].score);
```